# How do I delete podcasts downloaded by podbean?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, podcast

As far as I can tell from looking at the settings, all I can do is listen to the podcasts, and then the program will delete them.  I'd prefer if it didn't download them unless I tell it to, and allow me to delete them when I'm done listening to them.  I have a Lenovo TAB3 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you do:

1. Click the second icon from the left on the top that looks like a broadcast radio tower.
2. Down from that on the second toolbar from the top click "Downloads"
3. Click ""Downloaded"
4. Below there will be a list of podcasts that have been downloaded, select the one you want to delete, press your finger on it until a delete button is displayed in the center of the screen, and when you click that it will be deleted, it should free alot of space on the device.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd prefer if it didn't download them unless I tell it to...

Unless you click on the 3 dots (top right) to download, it won't. And you can remove downloads from same place

> .... allow me to delete them when I'm done listening to them

Settings → Disable *Delete Played episodes*

For more understanding on how the app works see this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKUaFKl7B5I&feature=youtu.be)